# Cypher query using prior row results

Tags: neo4j, row, hierarchy

I have a set of test results for tests w, x, y, and z that are measured independently on distinct samples. The test results create a hierarchical assembly of the samples.

Thus, you have a query which produces a list in each result line, such as:

```
row1: w, [13,5,16,21,11,19]
row2: x, [5,16,19]
row3: y, [5,19]
row4: z, [19]
```

This can be created with the following:

```
create (a:test{name:'w'})
create (b:test{name:'x'})
create (c:test{name:'y'})
create (d:test{name:'z'})
create (e:sample{number:13})
create (f:sample{number:5})
create (g:sample{number:16})
create (h:sample{number:21})
create (i:sample{number:11})
create (j:sample{number:19})
merge (a)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(e)
merge (a)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(f)
merge (a)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(g)
merge (a)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(h)
merge (a)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(i)
merge (a)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(j)
merge (b)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(f)
merge (b)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(g)
merge (b)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(j)
merge (c)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(f)
merge (c)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(j)
merge (d)-[:result{value:'+'}]->(j)
merge (d)-[:result{value:'-'}]->(f)
```

Then, the query might be:

```
match (t:test)-[r:result]->(s:sample) 
return t.name,collect(s.number +  r.value) as results 
order by size(results) desc
```

sample items drop out at each row because the measured parameter (w,x,y,z) changes from + to - or null. But I need to distinguish a negative value from an absence of data (null). I want to verify that w+,5 in row3 becomes y-, 5 in row4 rather than y becoming null for sample 5 in row4. And that sample 16 drops out because of an absence of data rather that a negative result for y.

This would be easy if the number of samples was small:

```
match (t:test)-[r:result]->(s:sample) 
return t.name,
collect(case when r.value='+' then s.number +  r.value else null end) as results,
collect(case when r.value='-' then s.number +  r.value else null end) as neg_result 
order by size(results) desc
```

, but in my scenario the sample size is very large and propagating the entire list will be messy.

Thus, the question: Is there a way to address, using cypher, a prior row's list to ask the question in the next row?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, it looks like you've already provided the actual current result (that first code sample you have). Can you give an example of the output that you would like to have? I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would like to have an output like the last query shown using the collect function. But there is a caveat. The number of negative results will be very large because I have a large starting base. So it will be very hard to see those dropping out. This would not be the case if I was just evaluating the samples in the prior row. So I am trying to see if I can instantiate the prior row's positive values and see why they dropped out (negative or null result).